# i am stuck in react router dom can anyone help me

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

HOw my website looking before commit
[click to view](https://fastnews77.netlify.app/)

**my App.js file**

```
 <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
        <Route  path=""  element={<DeliveredComponents />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} >
          <Route path="" element={<Allbogs />} />
          <Route path=":id" element={<Post />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} /> 
      </Route> 
 </Routes>
```

**DeliveredComponents file code**

```
 <div className=  "container mt-3 text-center" >
            <div className="row">  
                <div className="col-sm-3">{<LeftSideBar />}</div>
                <div className=" col-sm-6   ">
                    <div className="container row">
                        <div >{<Puzzle/>}</div>            
                        <div> 
                            <Routes> 
                               <Route index element={<Home />} />
                               <Route  path='/' element={<Home />} />  
                               <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                               <Route path="/category" element={<Category />} />
                          
                            </Routes>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">{<RightSideBar/>} </div>
                       
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to add a blog page to my website but I messed up

**Before my website**[Previous](https://fastnews77.netlify.app/)

**After adding blog routes**
[Click this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgj8L.jpg)

**Can you find where I did a mistake**

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the issue? Instead of sharing links to the webapps, can you edit the post to include the "previous" working code so it's easier to compare with what you may've changed for the "now" "not working" code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
```

If the path is `/`, all that is rendered is `<Navbar />`, which seems about right for your screenshot.